# PaperJS - angle between two points

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Any idea how one can get the angle between two path segments in paper js?

I've tried point1.getDirectedAngle(point2), and I don't quite understand the returned value, as it doesn't correspond to the real angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[getAngle(point)](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#getangle-point), [getAngleInRadians(point)](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#getangleinradians-point) and [getDirectedAngle(point)](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#getdirectedangle-point) all consider the given points as vectors.

The result is in degree except for getAngleInRadians().

So when you do

```
 point1.getDirectedAngle(point2)
```

`point1` must be the vector from your current point to the previous point, and `point2` must be the vector from your current point to the next point:

```
for segment in path.segments
    point1 = segment.previous.point.subtract(segment.point)
    point2 = segment.next.point.subtract(segment.point)
    angle = point1.getDirectedAngle(point2)
```